# Dokerfile python can't open file

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run python on a docker but I'm not getting it.

My **Dockerfile** looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /
CMD [ "python", "byPassCaptcha.py" ]
```

This is the error message:

> python: can't open file '/usr/src/app/byPassCaptcha.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'docker run --rm -it  recaptchabypass:latest'" terminated with exit code: 2.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: You're copying the files into `/`, not the current directory.  Try `COPY . .` in place of your current `ADD` line.

Comment: @DavidMaze returned this error ideone.com/ejqlW0, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Missing copying the file `byPassCaptcha.py`

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "byPassCaptcha.py" ]
```

Comment: returned this error https://ideone.com/ejqlW0, do you know why?

Comment: @Tiago This mean docker file works well and your file `byPassCaptcha.py` got the error.